# How to make a variable different in every for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a Discord bot, and I'm trying to make a command that returns the lyrics to a song. It all works fine, but every time the lyric API returns "\n\n\n" (which it does) I want it to put every paragraph into a different page in a DiscordUtils paginator. This means I would have to assign a value a variable every time I go through my for-loop. I don't know how I would be able to do this. Here's my code:

```py
@commands.command()
    async def lyrics(self, ctx, *, values):
        band, song = values.split(",")
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(f"https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/{band}/{song}") as lyrics:
                load = await lyrics.read()
                lyricdata = json.loads(load)
                lyricsraw = lyricdata["lyrics"]
                print(len(lyricsraw))
                try:
                    return
                    return
                    num = 0
                    embeds = []
                    for para in lyricsraw:
                        num += 1 = discord.Embed().add_field(name=f"{song} Lyrics Part {num}", value=para)
                        embeds.append(num)
                    paginator = DiscordUtils.Pagination.CustomEmbedPaginator(ctx, remove_reactions=True)
                    paginator.add_reaction('⏪', "back")
                    paginator.add_reaction('⏩', "next")
                    
                    await paginator.run(embeds)
            
                except KeyError:
                    await ctx.send("Invalid song or band name.")
```

I've tried plenty of different things and can't seem to find this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Guess you just have to put the variable definition into the for loop? Also what do you want to do with the 2 returns? They just block the whole code and the second one isn't even getting executed

Comment: The returns there I was just testing with and aren't i the final code